# Repeat and Double elements in lists in Prolog

Tags: prolog, predicate, list

how can I write two predicates that are described below.

1) Define the `double(X,Y)` predicate, which is true if the list Y contains each of the elements X
repeated twice. Example: `double([a,b],[a,a,b,b])` is true.

2) Define the predicate `repeat(X,Y,N)`, which is true if the list Y contains each of the elements X
repeated N times. For example, for the question `repeat([a,b],[a,a,a,b,b,b],3)`, Prolog answers true.

Could you give me the example of those predicates?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `repeat/3` you have `double/2`.

and thus:

```
multiple(X,N,R) :-
    length(R,N),maplist(=(X),R).
repeat(Li,Lo,N) :-
    maplist({N}/[Xi,Xo]>>multiple(Xi,N,Xo),Li,Nested),flatten(Nested,Lo).
```

But it doesn't run backwards due to the flatten/2 I think. Can that be improved?

Answer (score 0):

```
double([], []).
double([X|Y], [X,X|Z]) :- double(Y,Z).

remove_if_same(_,R,0,R):- !.                                                                             
remove_if_same(X,[X|Y],N,R) :- Nm1 is N-1,remove_if_same(X,Y,Nm1,R). 
repeat([],[],_).
repeat([X|Xr],Y,N) :- remove_if_same(X,Y,N,R), repeat(Xr,R,N).
```

How double works? 
If you've got two empty lists, then that is true, there is nothing to double from the first argument.

Otherwise, you're taking the head from the first list, and 2 head elements from the second list. If all these are the same (so if all are X) you're checking with recursion rest of elements, so accordingly Y and Z. So you'll check once again if lists are empty and so on, and if on any of the steps sth is not possible you return false.

About the repeat predicate, it's quite similar in reasoning.
2 things that I should explain:

1. The `!` mark will make that the command-line interface(like swipl) will not search for other results of the `remove_if_same`. It would work same if we pass it to the repeat.
2. remove_if_same statement uses the accumulator (the 4th argument) to return at the end of the search the list without N same elements.

Comment: Okay. I get it. Thank you very much.